# Type annotation signature for multiple return values

Tags: julia

What's the Julia syntax to add a return-type if you're returning multiple values?

For example, Given:

```
function basic_add(x::Float64)
    return x+1, Int(floor(x+1))
end
```

How do I add a return type?

Comment: You gain more by making your function more type generic and let Julia generate different methods based on the types used. You don't gain performance by making your functions like `C`.

Comment: @hesham_EE Doesn't type specification save interpreter from deriving the types and make your compilation simplier? I'd put a type wherever I can for the sake of readbility and in hope that makes program more deterministic.

Comment: @EPo No. It doesn't matter for performance and it hardly increases readability (in fact, I'd argue the opposite).

Comment: @crstnbr why was type annotation introduced in python then?  I think strong typing option is core Julia advantage over python, where annotation will show in lint, and Julia just will not compile.

Comment: @EPo You're right that Julia's type system is crucial to its performance, and that this is an important advantage over python. However, explicit type annotations in method signatures are completely irrelevant for performance. Julia knows the precise types of the inputs independent of those.

Comment: Type annotations within blocks of code are mostly (although not always) irrelevant because of Julia's type inference which, again, is only possible because of Julia's type system.

Comment: Maybe this should be discussed on the Julia Discourse instead of the comments of this question?

Comment: @Seanny123 definitely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Julia returns multiple values, it's actually returning a Tuple. Thus the return-type must be defined in terms of a Tuple:

```
function basic_add(x::Float64)::Tuple{Float64, Int}
    return x+1, floor(Int, x+1)
end
```

Also, as noted by Przemyslaw Szufel in the comments, you can also return a `NamedTuple`: `return (a=x+1, b=floor(Int, x+1))`

Comment: Although you're right about the Tuple part your answer isn't quite correct. Technically, you never return multiple values. In your case you return a single value as well, namely a tuple `(x+1, Int(floor(x+1)))`, which happens to be a container for multiple values.

Comment: Instead of `return x+1, Int(floor(x+1))`, which constructs a tuple, you could just as well `return [x+1, Int(floor(x+1))]` which would return a vector.

Comment: BTW, `floor` takes a type argument. It is more elegant, and slightly faster, to write `floor(Int, x)` instead of `Int(floor(x))`.

Comment: BTW a `NamedTuple` would look just nicer (especially in the case when you have more than two elements): `return (a=x+1, b=floor(Int, x+1))`